# Compute function to create variable that meets multiple conditions

Tags: spss

I'm trying to write syntax in SPSS that uses the compute variable command to create a new variable that looks at 5 other scale variables and finds the minimum variable among the five with a value greater than or equal to 0.80.

For example,

```
        CAT1 CAT2 CAT3 CAT4 CAT5
CASE 1  0.75 0.82 0.85 0.90 0.95
CASE 2  0.65 0.75 0.82 0.87 0.95
```

For case 1, the computed variable would return a value of 2.  For case 2, it would return a value of 3.

I'm stumped -- originally I thought it would work with a conditional MIN statement, but it's not working.  Thinking it might need an IF/THEN, but I'm hoping someone has a more efficient solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Several answers were already provided on the SPSSX-L list.

Answer (score 1):

this syntax will leave a zero in NewVar if all the categories are less than 0.8:

```
*creating sample data.
data list  list/ CAT1 to CAT5.
begin data
0.75 0.82 0.85 0.90 0.95
0.65 0.75 0.82 0.87 0.95
end data.

*calculating NewVar: the index number of the minimum category that is GE 0.8.
compute NewVar=0.
compute #tmp=max( CAT1 to CAT5)+1.
DO REPEAT cat=cat1 to cat5 / VL= 1 to 5.
  do if cat>=0.80 .
      if cat<#tmp NewVar=VL.
      compute #tmp=cat.
  end if.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```